# cannot import name 'Webclient' for python slack api

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Getting an error when trying to use slack web client

```
from slack import WebClient
client = WebClient(token="")
```

```
    from slack import WebClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient'
```

Comment: How did you install the module? E.g. what was your pip command?

Comment: Also, anywhere in that directory do you have a file called `slack.py`? If so, you have to rename it and delete any `slack.pyc` files too.

Comment: Looks like you accidentally installed the older version of the library, that does not have WebClient. Run this command to install the correct version: `pip3 install -U slackclient`